# Value contains too many decimal places. The maximum is 0. Lightswitch html client

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have columns of type `Decimal(5,2)` in sql. In LightSwitch, data type is `Decimal`.

If I have `8.50` stored in a field in sql, HTMLClient displays it as `8.5` and gives a client validation error while updating entity:

> The value 8.5 contains too many decimal places. The maximum is 0.

Please suggest a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @MegaTron for pointing me to right direction. 
Turns out, Decimal(Precision,Scale) was incorrectly mapped to (5,0). As I updated my data source, it mapped as (5,2) solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [Format Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674022(v=vs.110).aspx) property, you can specify how numeric and date types appear in an application that you create in Visual Studio LightSwitch.
Also perhaps [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2012/04/11/ui-design-improvements-part-1-formatting-numeric-data-andrew-lader.aspx) article will help you.